# correctly implementing iterators for custom class without using boost

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have made a `LinkedList` class. This is a `singly-linked-list` and I want to make a `forward_iterator` for this class. **I have made the code and i want to know whether i have implemented it correctly.** The source i referred to make this code is [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/).

```
template <class T>
struct node
{
    T data;
    node *next;
};

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
    private :
    node<T> *start;
    unsigned int numElements;
    // Assume all functions are implemented
};
```

Iterator Code :

```
class iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,node<T>*>
{
    node<T>* itr;

    public :

    iterator (node<T>* temp) : itr(temp) {}
    iterator (const iterator& myitr) : itr(myitr.itr) {}
    iterator& operator++ ()
    {
        itr = itr->next;
        return *this;

    }
    bool operator== (const iterator& rhs) 
    {
        return itr == rhs.itr;

    }
    bool operator!= (const iterator& rhs) 
    {
        return itr != rhs.itr;

    }
    T& operator*()
    {
        return itr->data;
    }

};
```

Q. Is the above implementation correct ?

Q. If no then what changes should i make ? Also do any additional thing needs to implemented ?

Comment: Looks like this is better suited for [SE CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: for people here it takes only a minute of effort to answer this...then y close this...?

Comment: I'd remove the user-declared copy constructor. The implicit one will do exactly the same thing, and it's deprecated to declare a copy constructor and not a destructor and copy-assignment operator.

Comment: @MikeSeymour will remove that....thank you for your time

Comment: missing `const` for `operator ==` and `!=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume that the missing parentheses in

```
iterator& operator++
```

are a typo (still, the compiler needs them there). Then you're only missing two things:

- the postfix `++` operator
- the `->` operator

So:

```
iterator operator++(int) {
  iterator result(*this);
  ++*this;
  return result;
}

T *operator->() {
  return &itr->data;
}
```

...and then you have fulfilled all requirements of the `ForwardIterator` concept.

Comment: yea that was just a typo

Comment: just one thing.... i have implemented `operator* ()` then why go on to implement `T *operator->()`

Comment: To enable expressions like `iter->some_member_of_T()` instead of just `(*iter).some_member_of_T()`.

Comment: @PRP: Because that's a requirement for an input iterator (and hence for a forward iterator). With just `operator*`, you couldn't do `it->member` to access a class member via an iterator (although of course you could do `(*it).member`).